# How can I properly calculate the size of a struct array? Am I doing this right?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, malloc

I am trying to get the total amount of bytes of an array of structs. The total bytes of 1 struct is 96 bytes. I put the int first to avoid padded bytes. I really don't know if what i'm doing is correct but i know that allocating struct[MAX] would be 96 bytes * 50 based on the sample  i pasted here. i get about 7 million bytes, or some garbage value. Anyone can help me calculate in code the amount of `struct address addr[MAX]` where `MAX = 50`. Here is the full sample. Thanks guys!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX 50  //for structure

struct address {
     int zip;   // 4 bytes
     char name[20];      // 20 bytes
     char street[40];    // 40 bytes
     char city[16];      // 16 bytes
     char state[4];      // 4 bytes
     char country[10];   // 10 bytes
};

int main()
{
    struct address addr[MAX];
    unsigned int *allocation;
    allocation = malloc(MAX * sizeof(struct address));

    if (!allocation) {
        printf("Memory allocation error\n\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("address start: 0x%x08 - size in bytes: %d\n", &addr, sizeof(struct address));
        printf("sizeof zip %d\n", sizeof(addr[0].zip));
        printf("sizeof name %d\n", sizeof(addr[0].name));
        printf("sizeof street %d\n", sizeof(addr[0].street));
        printf("sizeof city %d\n", sizeof(addr[0].city));
        printf("sizeof state %d\n", sizeof(addr[0].state));
        printf("sizeof country %d\n", sizeof(addr[0].country));
        printf("total size of structure is %d\n", allocation);
    }

    free(allocation);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `allocation` is the pointer on the allocated data, not its size... and why do you allocate the structure when it's already allocated as an auto variable?

Comment: I didn't know it was allocated. So i don't need malloc? and the allocation pointer? So to find the total bytes of the full struct array would be this: `totalBytes = MAX * sizeof(struct address);`?

Comment: no you don't need that.

Comment: ok thanks. its becoming a little clear. I really want to understand this before I start producing a project.

Comment: would i be able to do something like this: `int totalBytes = MAX * sizeof(struct address);`

Comment: yes that would work

Comment: Pointer variable `allocation` was used incorrectly eveywhere except in the actual `malloc`. Its type should have been `struct address *allocation;` and printing `printf("total size of structure is %d\n", allocation);` is a terrible way to print a pointer.

Comment: The size of the memory is the amount you told `malloc` to allocate, namely `MAX * sizeof(struct address)`. It is useless to look at the pointer `malloc`returns to establish anything except the base address of the allocated memory, if any. There is **no other information** available from that pointer.

Comment: Sorry. I am new to this. I am learning from you guys so i can avoid what i'm currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
   printf("total size of structure is %d\n", allocation);
```

Is incorrect as `allocation` is a pointer. To get the total size simply do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 50  //for structure

struct address{
     int zip;   // 4 bytes
     char name[20];      // 20 bytes
     char street[40];    // 40 bytes
     char city[16];      // 16 bytes
     char state[4];      // 4 bytes
     char country[10];   // 10 bytes
};

int main()
{
    struct address addr[MAX];
    printf("Size %zu\n", sizeof(addr));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [edit] ok i deleted it and posted as a comment. Thank you very much! I just want to get a decent grasp on memory management. I don't want to write projects without understand what's going on in the memory and processor. I'm also learning x86 asm at the same time. Thank you for clearing this up for me.

Comment: @EdHeal: sizeof gives a size_t, not an int, so perhaps you should either cast the value or change the %i.

Comment: I got the right calculation from your change. Thanks. I did it on paper first.  Size_t is a generic int I believe

Answer (score 0):

```
struct address addr[MAX]
```

with this line you allocated structure from addr[0] to addr[49]